# Xcode 5 DP5 fails to download iOS 7 doc set

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

When I download the iOS 7 doc set, Xcode says *my account does not have access to iOS 7 doc sets*. The account I used had joined the developer program and paid the $99 / year. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: How can i know i did buy it or not?

Comment: @jeffrey What do you mean "how can I know if I bought it"? You should know whether or not you spent $99. To see which memberships are going to expire (and when) and which ones are available for purchase, head over to the Member Center or your profile page.

Comment: @RazorSharp Expiration Date: April, 26, 2014

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details - rather than leaving lots of comments. By providing more details, you may also be able to get better answers from the SO community.

Comment: Head to the dev forums. There's a discussion about this over there.

Comment: @RazorSharp i have upload a screenshot obove

Comment: I thought xcode 5 was still under NDA. I suggest you ask Apple forums or tech support.

Comment: Of course, breaching the NDA is one way to guarantee you don't have access in the future.